# Executing worker specific code

Tags: python, celery

I have the following project: https://github.com/gonvaled/celery-test

I would like to have some code which is only executed in the worker, but I do not know how to do this.

This is the worker running:

```
pegasus $ celery worker --app=proj
This should only be executed in the worker

 -------------- celery@pegasus v3.0.9 (Chiastic Slide)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** --- . broker:      amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- . app:         tasks:0x98d188c
- ** ---------- . concurrency: 2 (processes)
- ** ---------- . events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
- ** ---------- 
- *** --- * --- [Queues]
-- ******* ---- . celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
--- ***** ----- 

[2012-12-22 17:50:31,868: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@pegasus has started.
```

And this is the client running:

```
$ python client.py 
This should only be executed in the worker
8
```

The client should not print `This should only be executed in the worker`. Obviously, I need to protect that part of the code somehow, but I do not know how. How can I make sure that some code is only run in the worker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is based on a global variable, in module `gd.py` (global data), which I instantiate when the client is imported, and *before* any worker code is imported.

This is my client code:

```
import gd
gd.CLIENT_ACTIVE = True
# import worker here
....
```

In my worker, I do:

```
import gd
if not getattr(gd, 'CLIENT_ACTIVE', None)
    # worker specific code here
```